# What is the 'mlefit' argument passed into the statsmodel.discrete.LogitResults?

Tags: python, statsmodels

Here's the code:

```
from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import LogitResults, Logit
LogitResults(Logit(y,X).fit())
```

Here's the error:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mlefit'
```

I'm assuming 'mlefit' refers to maximum likelihood estimation fit. But what kind of data am I supposed to pass into it?

Comment: Hmm, this is the first time I've heard of this being required. Maybe switch over to `scikit` and run the regression from there.

Comment: Conversely why not do, `logit_model = Logit(y, X).fit()` and then call on `logit_model.summary()`

Comment: I would but the outputs I want from LogitResults isn't something you can get from Logit.

Answer (score 0):

`Logit(y,X).fit()` already returns a (wrapped) LogitResults instance, so there is not need to do anything like this.

If you would like to do something like this anyway, the first argument in the signature of `LogitResults.__init__` (`DiscreteResults.__init__`) is the model instance and the second is the base results instance.

e.g. a **redundant** call that should work is

```
my_model = Logit(y,X)
my_result = LogitResults(my_model, my_model.fit())
```

or more likely the second line needs to be

```
my_result = LogitResults(my_model, my_model.fit()._results)
```

(This works around an internal feature to integrate with pandas.)

Comment: I removed my initial answer, because upon rereading the question, I don't think the OP wants the explanation about the internal details.